# WordPress: How do I get all posts from $wp_query in the search results?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I must be brain dead, I can't figure out how to get ALL posts from the `$wp_query` so that I can create a widget filter for the search results.

`$wp_query->posts` only gives me the posts that are going to be displayed in the list, so, if `posts_per_page` is set to 10, I only get 10 posts. I need them all so I can sort them and display a filter based on all posts from the search results.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could try to use: http://generatewp.com/wp_query/

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Set posts_per_page parameter in args to -1, this will return all posts from wp_posts table. for example

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'post_type'        => 'post',
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Now you can loop through and get posts

```
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
  // go ahead
}
```

Comment: Yes, but that will display all posts on the page. I want to keep pagination. But I also want to be able to have filters for the results.

Comment: But you cannot do this by same WP_Query, You need to setup separate WP_Query for this.

Answer (score -1):

Display a filter based on all posts from the search results.

```
     <?php

    /*pass your search string here example like this ( 's'=>'test' ) */
   $args=array('s'=>'test','order'=> 'DESC', 'posts_per_page'=>get_option('posts_per_page'));

   $query=new WP_Query($args);

    if( $query->have_posts()): 

    while( $query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();

     {
     echo $post->post_title;
     echo $post->post_content;
     }

    endwhile; 
    else:
    endif;
  ?>
```